# Exporting PostGIS Geometry POINT as Label text to DXF or DGN

Tags: postgis, export, ogr2ogr, dxf, dgn

I need to **export**, by the **ogr2ogr** command or similar, **text** information related to a geometry position from my **PostgreSQL**(with PostGIS) database to an **AutoCAD DXF** layer file or to a **Microstation DGN** layer file, so I can later show that information in the AutoCAD/Microstation GIS.

I have been looking through internet for so many days but all I can get is a layer with geometry points, I always lose the text label information. I know there is the **"Text" element type in DGN** and the **"MTEXT/TEXT" element type in DXF**, so I need to generate that kind of features.

In Shapefiles I know that I can export new attribute fields with that information but it have to be obtained in DXF/DGN format.

I need to made it automatic with some kind of server command like GDAL ogr2ogr, but I have tried with the "-select" (getting the text SQL SELECT attribute) or "-lco" or "-dsco" options without any result...

Those are my commands:

```
ogr2ogr -select "Text" -f DXF text_layer.dxf "PG:host=192.168.1.* user=**** password=**** dbname=****" -sql "SELECT position AS the_geom, name as Text FROM the_geometry_table"

ogr2ogr -select "Text" -f DGN text_layer.dgn "PG:host=192.168.1.* user=**** password=**** dbname=****" -sql "SELECT position AS the_geom, name as Text FROM the_geometry_table"
```

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the OGR DXF Driver document,
[dxf driver](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_dxf.html)

Point features with LABEL styling are written as MTEXT entities based on the styling information.

The OGR Feature Style is available here,
[OGR Style guide](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/ogr_feature_style.html)
 ,look for - Label Tool Parameters.

To define the Label style:

You can add a field named OGR_STYLE to your Postgresql table and populate with something like this,
"LABEL(f:"Times New Roman",s:12pt,t:{text_string})"
text_string is the field you want to display as text in the DXF.

When you run ogr2ogr to convert your Point geometry to DXF, ogr should automatically detect OGR_STYLE and output MText in the dxf.

Comment: Oh yeah! It works, thank you klewis, it was much time spent..
Finally I decided to generate de OGR_STYLE field in the SQL query like: `SELECT posicion AS the_geom, 'LABEL(f:\'Times New Roman\',s:12pt,t:\'' || name || '\')' AS OGR_STYLE FROM the_geometry_table c [...]`, and it became the Text attribute of the DXF Point object :)