.SHP to .DXF while preserving the labels
I have a shapefile layer containing points that hold their name as an attribute and I displayed those names as labels using QGIS . Now when I try to export these points as .dxf file the label is not contained within the exported file. Is there a way I can do this in QGIS (using the GUI or programatically) or using a python library?

see https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/73461/276 you can use gdal to export from a shapefile point to MTEXT DXF file.
